# How to create one to one relationship in DevExpress XPO classes?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, gridcontrol, xpo

Shortly,

Here's a schema

**User Table**

[image: User Table]

**Category Table**

[image: Category table]

1. A user have a categoryID
2. All I need to populate a GridControl with User_ID, CategoryID, **CategoryName**
3. Note that CategoryName is only belongs to second table (Category Table)

**What I do Is:**

Create Models (User, Category) Note that primary key is composite so it must be structure
https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/a2615/xpo-how-to-map-persistent-objects-to-database-tables-with-compound-or-composite-multi#

```
// Composite key must be a struct
public struct user_key
{
    [Persistent("user_brn")]
    public int user_brn { get; set; }
    [Persistent("user_num")]
    public int user_num { get; set; }
}

[Persistent("Users")]
public class User : XPLiteObject
{
    public User(Session session) : base(session) { }

    [Key, Persistent] 
    public user_key key;    // user_brn, user_num

    [Persistent("user_name")]
    public string user_name { get; set; }

    [Persistent("CategoryID")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [NonPersistent, Association("user_category")]
    public Category Category
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [PersistentAlias("Category.CategoryName")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }            // I think it will work. But it doesn't
}


[Persistent("Category")]
public class Category : XPLiteObject
{
    public Category(Session session) : base(session) { }

    [Key, Persistent("CategoryID")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Persistent("CategoryName")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    private User _user;
    [NonPersistent, Association("user_category")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

GridView code

```
 IDataLayer dal = 
 XpoDefault.GetDataLayer(MSSqlConnectionProvider.GetConnectionString(" 
 (local)", "testdb"), AutoCreateOption.DatabaseAndSchema);
 Session session = new Session(dal);
 XPCollection collection = new XPCollection(session, typeof(User));
 gridControl1.DataSource = collection;
```

**Result: = fail**

[image: Result]

What I should do? Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` class, remove the property `CategoryId` and alter your `Category`  property as follows:

```
[Persistent("CategoryID")]
public Category Category
{
    get; set;
}
```

and change your CategoryName property:

```
[PersistentAlias("Category.CategoryName")]
public string CategoryName 
{ 
    get
    {
        return (string)EvaluateAlias(nameof(CategoryName));
    }
}
```

The reference from `Category` back to `User` is trickier, since there's no persistent field to back it. You could try it with a free join:

```
[PersistentAlias("[<User>][Category = '@This.CategoryID'].Single()")]
public User User 
{ 
    get
    {
        return (User)EvaluateAlias(nameof(User));
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: Unless you need XPO to map to an existing DB structure, I would recommend using the XPObject as base class. It offers greater flexibility but requires schema changes, such as the ObjectType column.

Comment: @deveton could you check if my answer works for you and upvote if satisfied? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a one to one relationship the tables should have the same keys.

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647272/threadsafedatalayer-and-idatalayer-devexpress-xpo-cant-map-classinfo-to-same-ta

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but inheritance can be selected to be implemented with a 1:1 relationship.  See [Inheritance Mapping documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/2125/create-a-data-model/inheritance-mapping#map-each-class-to-its-own-table).